# Can I specify the schema location in a RELAX NG compact schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, relaxng

I want to use a Relax NG compact schema.  Do I specify the .rnc file in the `xsi:schemaLocation` the way I would for an XSD? I don't want to convert the Relax NG to an XSD because the limitations of XSD that would be a problem in my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

xsi:schemaLocation is specific to XML Schema.

If you need to specify the location of a RNG schema in a document (the usefulness of this practice is not always obvious ;), you can use an [XML Model Processing Instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/NOTE-xml-model-20110811/#the-xml-model-processing-instruction) (assuming of course that you use a tool that supports it, the recommendation being still young).

Comment: I can use an XML Model Processing instruction for RNC files also (compact Relax NG) or just just Relax NG in XML format (RNG)?  Is the use of an instruction the way Relax NG is usually implemented or do most people not have anything in the XML?

Comment: You can use it to associate a RELAX NG using the compact syntax: `<?xml-model href="file:/tmp/test.rnc" type="application/relax-ng-compact-syntax"?>`. This kind of attachment can be useful, but there are many cases where it's more convenient to let the application that processes the document choose the schema to use (one of the reasons being that it's not always safe to follow the schema location given by the document itself).